# Как вычислить значение выражения посредством рекурсии

Tags: c++, математика, ряды

Как написать рекурсивную функцию для этого выражения:
p=a<sub>0</sub>+x(a<sub>1</sub>+x(a<sub>2</sub>+x(a<sub>3</sub>+...+x(a<sub>n</sub>))))

Comment: соотношения между `а` неизвестны?

Comment: это элементы массива(любые)

Comment: `x = i => i==n ? 0 : a[i] + x(i-1); x(0)`

Comment: Это у вас вызов функции `x()` или умножение на переменную `x`? а то у нас тут мнения разошлись :)

Answer (score 3):

Например, [так](http://ideone.com/99uRIM):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

const int N = 5;

double A[N] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

double calc(double x, double* a, int n = 0)
{
    if (n == N-1) return a[n];
    return calc(x,a,n+1)*x+a[n];
}

double series(double x, double* a)
{
    double sum = 0.0;
    for(int i = N-1; i >= 0; --i)
        sum = sum*x + a[i];
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    for(double x = 0.0; x < 5.0; x += 0.5)
    {
        cout << setw(8) << calc(x,A) << "   " << setw(8) << series(x,A) << endl;
    }
}
```

`series` - вычисление "в лоб", для сравнения...

Comment: хм, а мне показалось, что x - имя функции))

Comment: А мне - что это схема Горнера...

Answer (score 1):

Не уверен что будет компилироваться. Но думаю как то так будет выглядеть.

```
int sum(int n[], int i) {
 if (i == 0) {
    return 0;
  }
  return n[i] + sum(n, i--);
}
```